# Android Recyclerview Horizontal is not displaying if i open keyboard and closed

Tags: android, keyboard, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I am using `recyclerview` in my activity, first i used vertical scroll view it's working fine, now i changed to horizontal scroll view. It's working fine without open keyboard if i open keyboard the view is clearing. So i checked my code, the problem is in my horizontal scroll view. I don't know how to solve this can some one can help me to solve this problem. Please find my code and image attachment after i open keyboard and closed my UI is erased.

```
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        addExpenseImageAdapter = new AddExpenseImageAdapter(AddExpenseActivity.this, imageBeanList);
        addExpenseImageAdapter.onImageAddClick(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(addExpenseImageAdapter);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give static height for `recyclerview`

Answer (score 0):

You have to setLayoutManager after setAdapter to the recyclerView and check the imageBeanList size also.